# Gem Wicked_pdf - ao quebrar página repete a primeira linha da tabela

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Quando tem uma tabela e os registros não cabem em uma página só, na nova página o wicked_pdf repete a primeira linha atrapalhando a leitura da segunda página.
Como faço para não exibir essa primeira linha? (Componentes Curriculares - Módulo 1).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa alterar a propriedade display da tag thead. Adicione o código abaixo no arquivo css que é específico para renderizar o pdf, por exemplo: app/assets/stylesheets/pdf.css

```
thead {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Lembrando que este arquivo precisa ser incluído no template do pdf através da tag

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf' -%>
```